# Context.Response.Headers' threw an exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, http-headers, httpresponse

I'm trying to generate a PDF using a memory stream. When clears the headers, it threw `Server cannot clear headers after HTTP headers have been sent`. Here is my code snippet.

```
Context.Response.Clear();
Context.Response.ClearHeaders();
Context.Response.ClearContent();

System.IO.MemoryStream st = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
st = (MemoryStream)levyStream;
byte[] b = st.ToArray();

 Context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="+MyFilename);
 Context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", b.Length.ToString());
 Context.Response.BufferOutput = true;
 Context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 Context.Response.Charset = "";

 Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(b, 0, (int)st.Length);
 Context.Response.Flush();
 st.Close();
```

I have attached an error in response object along with this.

[image]

Regards,
Aruna

Comment: wondering if you're facing this in IE11 only. Have you tried other browsers? Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using IIS 7.  If so, you need to change the application pool type from classic to integrated.  The integrated pipeline mode is IIS 7 specific.